# How can I make it so that a form's Text property will always equal a textbox's?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, text

Is it possible to have the System.Windows.Forms Text property to equal the text in a certain textbox?

For example:

[image]

Is it possible to have "Name" automatically change to "The Vanguard Group, Inc."? And every other time when the Institution Name is different?

Maybe something like:
   `Me.Text = InstitutionNameTextBox.Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just handle [`Control.TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, like this:

```
Private Sub InstitutionNameTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InstitutionNameTextBox.TextChanged
    Me.Text = InstitutionNameTextBox.Text
End Sub
```

Of course this doesn't prevent `Me.Text` being set from elsewhere, in which case you may have a different value.